# Block device doesn't actually mount and no errors are reported

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, amazon-web-services

I'm debugging an issue with mounting a partition (from an EBS volume) on an AWS EC2 instance.

The device shows up as `/dev/nvme1n1p1`:

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0         7:0    0 67.6M  1 loop /snap/lxd/20326
loop1         7:1    0 55.4M  1 loop /snap/core18/2066
loop2         7:2    0 33.3M  1 loop /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/3552
loop3         7:3    0 32.3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/12159
nvme0n1     259:0    0    8G  0 disk 
└─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0    8G  0 part /
nvme1n1     259:2    0    8G  0 disk 
└─nvme1n1p1 259:3    0    8G  0 part
```

I can try mounting it:

`sudo mount /dev/nvme1n1p1 /home/ubuntu/mystuff -v`

and it will report:

`mount: /dev/nvme1n1p1 mounted on /home/ubuntu/mystuff`

But it's *not actually mounted!* I can't see any files, and the lsblk output doesn't change from above (i.e. no mountpoint).

The kernel log only shows:

```
[ 2158.436056] BTRFS info (device nvme1n1p1): disk space caching is enabled
[ 2158.436057] BTRFS info (device nvme1n1p1): has skinny extents
[ 2158.446309] BTRFS info (device nvme1n1p1): enabling ssd optimizations
```

How do I debug this? Where can I get more information or insight into what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have (or had) an /etc/fstab entry for the same mountpoint but a different device. Due to a badly implemented feature in the systemd manager (which was supposed to remove mounts in case the device disappears), it automatically removes mounts *whenever* the device doesn't exist – and sometimes prioritizes the stale information from /etc/fstab over the "live" mount information. This sometimes results in new mounts being immediately unmounted.

- Check `journalctl -n 100` to see if this is the problem.
- Remove the entry from /etc/fstab, then run `systemctl daemon-reload` before mounting the device again.
- Try to mount the device at a different location.

Comment: Thank you!!!! I even tried removing the old fstab entry but I didn't know I had to run `systemctl daemon-reload` (or even that systemd was the issue)!